# React JS - Handle loading states of two queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

In my home page, I have to load some **posts** and **songs** from the database. Currently, I initially set a `loading` state variable to true, and then inside a `useEffect`, perform a `get` request for the `posts` and `songs`, store them in state, and once they have been fetched and stored, then set `loading` to false. I would simply display a loading spinner if `loading` was true, else I would display and loop over `posts` and `songs`

However, I want to display the `posts` and `songs` as soon as they are available, therefore if the `posts` are loaded faster than the `songs`, I want to display the `posts` and then a loading spinner below the displayed posts, indicating the songs are still being loaded.

My current solution to this is to have two `loading` state variables for `posts` and `songs`, such as `loadingPosts` and `loadingSongs`, and then have the following conditions to check if they are loading:

```
loadingPosts && <Spinner /> : <div>  Map over and display posts </div>
loadingSongs && <Spinner /> : <div>  Map over and display songs</div>
```

However, I would like  a cleaner and more concise method to handle this. After researching, I discovered `react-query` to potentially help with this issue. Could `react-query` be used to simplify this code? Also, are there any tradtional **react** methods to simplify this? Thanks.

Comment: Don't think there is anything wrong with your approach, as you will most likely also need to have error handling for these so keeping them separate is a good idea.

But for cleanliness perhaps split into to components

Comment: Your code snippet should be using `?` instead of `&&` to pair with the `:`

Comment: @GregFenton Yes sorry my mistake. However, any suggestions to improve the above code?

Comment: I agree with @DevonRay's responses.  First: your code above is just fine.  Second, his code below is a decent alternative.  To me the first thing to worry about is the user experience while waiting for data to load (remember, in production things typically are slower than when everything runs on "localhost")....so are the spinners or blank spaces or whatever a good experience for the user?  Once you know what you want to do, code accordingly :)

Comment: @DevonRay Any idea how to accomplish a solution with `react-query`? If so, could you provide an example?

Comment: @GregFenton If you see the answer below by **0stone0**, couldn't a potential issue with this solution be that if there are actually no posts or songs in the database, then a loading spinner would be loaded forever?

Comment: @GregFenton As the answer is relying on the length of the arrays for `posts` and `songs`

Comment: Yes.  So that's where I personally prefer to use an `isLoading` state variable.  You could do it without one if  you have an initial state set to something like `null` (no data has been loaded yet) and upon receiving the data you set the value to an array (possibly empty).  Then your code could have 3 states: `null` (still loading), `[]` (loaded, no data), or `[ ...... ]` (loaded, have data).

Personally I prefer to not overload a variable to do "multiple things".  I prefer to separate concerns (one variable for "loading status" and one for "data").

Comment: @GregFenton Ok so, you could initialize to null (meaning it's `loading`) and then check whether array is empty or has content (no longer `loading`), and then render the conent. However, having a seperate `isLoading` state variable is arguably better as it seperates "data" from  "loading status". is this correct?

Comment: "Better" is a relative term and thus arguable  :)  I prefer separation of responsibilities in my variables and data structures, so yes I would say this is "better in general".  If we were writing code for a very specific environment (a tiny device, the Space Shuttle, etc.) then I might argue otherwise.  So as with most things in software development: "this approach is better...depending on the requirements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Query can indeed simplify this process by handling data fetching, caching, and state management for you. It's especially helpful when dealing with multiple asynchronous requests like fetching posts and songs.

With React Query, you can manage multiple queries and display loading states for each query independently. Here's an example of how you might structure this using React Query:

```
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';

const Home = () => {
  const {
    data: posts,
    isLoading: isLoadingPosts,
    isError: isErrorPosts,
  } = useQuery('posts', fetchPosts);

  const {
    data: songs,
    isLoading: isLoadingSongs,
    isError: isErrorSongs,
  } = useQuery('songs', fetchSongs);

  if (isErrorPosts || isErrorSongs) {
    // Handle error states
    return <div>Error fetching data</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoadingPosts ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <div>
          {posts && posts.map((post) => (
            // Display posts
            <div key={post.id}>{/* Post content */}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}

      {isLoadingSongs ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <div>
          {songs && songs.map((song) => (
            // Display songs
            <div key={song.id}>{/* Song content */}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

// Example fetch functions (replace these with your actual API calls)
const fetchPosts = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('API_ENDPOINT_FOR_POSTS');
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Error fetching posts');
  }
  return response.json();
};

const fetchSongs = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('API_ENDPOINT_FOR_SONGS');
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Error fetching songs');
  }
  return response.json();
};

export default Home;
```

This approach allows React Query to manage the loading state, error handling, and caching of data fetched from your API endpoints. You define the fetch functions (fetchPosts and fetchSongs) to retrieve the data, and React Query takes care of the rest, simplifying your component logic significantly.

Comment: Thanks for the example, however could you give me a simple example of how would I implement caching relating to the api calls in the example you provided above?

Comment: React Query automatically caches the data by default when you use the useQuery hook. There's no specific configuration needed to enable caching; it's handled internally.

When you make a query using useQuery with a specific key, React Query stores the fetched data in its cache. If the same query (identified by the same key) is made again, React Query will return the cached data instead of making another network request.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, are there any traditional react methods to simplify this?

Well instead of using a load state, you could check if the state (array) is empty, and if they're both empty, show the loading state.

You could do this inline, but I personally prefer this way since it's more readable.

---

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    const [songs, setSongs] = useState([]);
  
    const postContent = (posts.length)
      ? posts.map(post => <p>{post}</p>)
      : null;
      
    const songContent = (songs.length)
      ? songs.map(song => <p>{song}</p>)
      : null;
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setPosts(p => [ ...p, 'post #' + (p.length + 1) ])}>Add post</button>
            <button onClick={() => setSongs(s => [ ...s, 'song #' + (s.length + 1) ])}>Add song</button>
            <p>
                {postContent}
                {songContent}
            </p>
            {(!postContent && !songContent) && (
                <p>
                    <em>Loading!</em><br />
                    <sub>Press one of the 'add' buttons to mimic the API call</sub>
                </p>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: however, what if the posts or song  actually had no records in the database, therefore their length would be `0`. This would mean the application would still render a loading spinner in place of `posts` or `songs`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom hook for fetching the data. It would be cleaner and reusable also. You can add error handling also.

```
const useFetcher = (url) => {
   const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false)
   const [data,setData] = useState(null)
   const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false)
   
   useEffect(() => {
      setIsFetching(true)
      fetch(url)
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(data => {
             setIsFetching(false)
             setData(data)
          })
         .catch(error => {
             setIsFetching(false)
             setIsError(false)
         });
   }, [url])

   return {
      isFetching, isError, data
   }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using a `.finally()` on your `fetch()` to ensure that `setIsFetching(false)` happens.  That way you don't need to code the same logic in  2 different places.  For the above example it is pretty trivial but in a more complex real-world scenario, using `.finally()` for unsetting necessary properties is cleaner and safer.